# JavaFX, Intelliji Idea, не работает FXMLLoader

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, maven, fxml

Проблема очень распространенная, гуглил полдня - ничего не работает. Уже просто не знаю что делать)

Классический автоматически сгенерированный код:

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
    System.out.println("Hello!");
```

Организация файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `sample.fxml` прописано `fx:controller="sample.Controller"`

Я запихнул этот sample.fxml куда только можно, пробовал задать путь для getResource всеми путями, включая полный путь на диске, но компилятор упорно выдает ошибку:

> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Я попытался в самом начале просто создать новый экземпляр:

`FXMLLoader mainLoader = new FXMLLoader();`

Но все равно возникает ошибка и показывает на эту строчку.

Гуглю полдня, все ответы сводятся к тому, что неправильно написан путь к файлу, но, как я уже говорил, я указывал его всеми возможными способами, и закидывал этот файл в каждую папку проекта - без результата. Самое обидное что этот же проект на домашнем компьютере вполне себе запускается.

Текст ошибки:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x7abf4dcd) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x7abf4dcd
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: 1. `fxml` должен быть в `resources` папке. 2. Загружайте `fxml` так: `Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml")`

Comment: fxml лежит в папке.
Через Main.class к сожалению не сработало.

Comment: В какой папке? `stacktrace` выложите пожалуйста. Ибо ошибка `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`  может означать разные вещи. Возможно у Вас ошибка в самом `fxml`.

Comment: Файл xml лежит в папке resourses, и на всякий случай так же и в папке с файлом Controller.

Stacktrace вот

Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

больше не дает выложить

Comment: Выложите весь текст ошибки в текст вопроса.

Comment: Выложил, пардон, не сразу сообразил

Comment: Не подключен модуль JavaFX. Внимательно читать ошибку надо.

Comment: так подключен, и на другом компе этот же код с этими же зависимостями работает)

Comment: Java какая стоит на обеих машинах? модули появились с Java 9. В Java 8 JavaFX встроенный.

Comment: на обеих 12 java, в настройках проекта и там и там стоит 12-я

Comment: Настраивайте модуля javafx